# Proving that ${\Delta}^2 $ of f actually lies in field K

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

This result is left unproved in Hungerfor Algebra on page 271 and I am asking for a proof verification here.

> Let K be a field with char K$\neq$2 and f$\in$ K[x] a polynomial of degree n with n distinct roots $u_1,..., u_n$ in some splitting field F of f over K. Let $\Delta = \prod_{i<j} (u_i -u_j) \in F$, and discriminant is D= ${\Delta}^2$.

Prove that D lies in K.

Assume that $\sigma ({\Delta}^2) = {\Delta}^2$ for all $\sigma \in Aut_{K} F $ and F is galois over K.

It implies that fixed field of K in F is K . So, K={for all v $\in F $ st $\sigma(v) = v $ for all $\sigma \in $ H}.So, v must belong to K.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, but you need to “prove” that $\sigma(\Delta^2)=\Delta^2$, not just “assume” it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is to show that $\sigma(D) = D$, where $D = \Delta^2$. To do this, remember that each element $\sigma \in {\rm Aut}_K{F}$ acts on the roots $u_1, \dots, u_n$ of $f(x)$ by *permutation*. So the argument boils down to verifying that the expression $D = \left( \prod_{i < j}(u_i - u_j)\right)^2$ is invariant under permutations of the roots $u_1, \dots, u_n$.

Next, we need to explain *why* the fixed field of ${\rm Aut}_K{F}$ in $F$ is $K$. Answer: $F$ is a *Galois* extension of $K$, and we can appeal to the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

In the first paragraph, we showed that $D$ is in the fixed field of ${\rm Aut}_K{F}$, and in the second paragraph, we showed that the fixed field of ${\rm Aut}_K{F}$ is $K$, hence $D$ must be in $K$.